# MySQL vs PostgreSQL performance with a complex query matching patterns

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a complex database, with around 30 tables. One table has more than 500,000 rows and another more than 15,000 and I use both in a separate database until today I decided to implement in only one database.

Before today, the table with 500,000 rows was in a MySQL database and the 15,000 row table was in PostgreSQL. In one page of heavy use, this was the result in a PHP benchmark:

```
getSimilarAvaiable - 0.0287 s
getUnavaiable - 0.27 s
ProcessDataOfUnavaiable - 1.4701 s
Process - 1.8622 s
TotalPageTime - 3.631 s
```

After I migrate everything to PostgreSQL, and use **the same SQL code** without any changes the result of the same page was this:

```
getSimilarAvaiable - 2.7465 s
getUnavaiableCars - 9.0763 s
ProcesseDataOfUnavaiableCars - 1.4167 s
ProcessCars - 1.7207 s
TotalPageTime - 14.9602 s
```

I put everything the same in MySQL, same index, everything, but I can't understand why there is this huge difference.  What I should do to optimize this?

**EDIT**: Now better explained.

The 500.00 table is composed with the follow structure:

```
id - bigint (primary key)
plate- varchar(10) Unique key
manufacturer - varchar(30)
vin - varchar(30)
```

The major query is something like this:

```
SELECT plate, vin, 1 as n, substr(plate,1,2) as l 
FROM imtt_vin WHERE substr(plate,1,1) >= 'A' and substr(plate,1,1) <= 'Z' AND
(manufacturer ILIKE '%".self::$Manufacturer."%') AND vin LIKE ?
UNION
SELECT plate, vin, 3 as n, substr(plate,4,2) as l 
FROM imtt_vin WHERE substr(plate,4,1) >= 'A' and substr(plate,4,1) <= 'Z' AND
(manufacturer ILIKE '%".self::$Manufacturer."%') AND vin LIKE ?
UNION
SELECT plate, vin, 2 as n, substr(plate,7,2) as l 
FROM imtt_vin WHERE substr(plate,7,1) >= 'A' and substr(plate,7,1) <= 'Z' AND 
(manufacturer ILIKE '%".self::$Manufacturer."%') AND vin LIKE ?
ORDER BY n, l, plate;
```

EDIT2: Tested with a complex single query and I reduced it from 15 to 8/9 seconds. Even so it is too much for me.

Comment: @David Believe me 30 tables and 500,000 rows is far from complex :)

Comment: Are you using MyISAM in MySQL or InnoDB? MyISAM is much faster, but supports less features.

Comment: Without seeing any of your queries or the structure of the involved tables and indexes, it will be extremely difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see how the queries are executed. Create some indexes using substr() as well, that might improve things a lot: EXPLAIN will show it to you.

Comment: Versions of your programs? Definition of indexes? Output of EXPLAIN / EXPLAIN ANALYZE? Tables read only? Or how frequent are write operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were using MyISAM in MySQL the performance difference could theoretically (because not much has been exposed regarding your database design and queries performed) be explained. Regarding cross performance between the two RDBMS I'd recommend you take a look at [this comparison page](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL#MySQL%3aMyISAM) (Anchored to the MyISAM section).

Comment: Yes, i use MyISAM. I post in first post the structure and query i use.

Comment: @DavidMagalhães: MyISAM is very fast for primitive, brute force queries. I think the index I outlined for PostgreSQL can still nuke it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to post EXPLAIN yourquery (for mysql) and EXPLAIN ANALYZE yourquery (for postgres) ; without that it's impossible to say anything relevant.

Also SELECT pg_relation_size('imtt_vin')

For instance what is the value of "?" in this query ?

```
SELECT plate, vin, 1 as n, substr(plate,1,2) as l 
FROM imtt_vin WHERE substr(plate,1,1) >= 'A' and substr(plate,1,1) <= 'Z' AND
(manufacturer ILIKE '%".self::$Manufacturer."%') AND vin LIKE ?
```

I don't know about license plates where you work but this part :

```
WHERE substr(plate,1,1) >= 'A' and substr(plate,1,1) <= 'Z'
```

probably selects all rows in the database, thus its only purpose is to burn CPU cycles. You could at least rewrite it (and all the others) like this to avoid a call to substr() :

```
WHERE substr(plate,1,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
```

And of course remove the condition when it is not useful.

Then we have :

```
manufacturer ILIKE '%".self::$Manufacturer."%'
```

Bad database design : are there 500.000 car manufacturers in the world ? Probably not. You should put the manufacturers in another table and use a foreign key. That would turn this unindexable condition into an indexable one.

For the rest, post EXPLAIN / EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: The condition is not actually "unindexable". There is a way. Outlined it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL uses more memory by default.  I think it is assigned to use more than 256MB by def install.  Not sure on the exact number.  PostgreSQL by default is set to use something like 32MB.  Try to bump each one up to 1GB of ram in config file then run benchmarks and get back to us.

Comment: Both use 16MB or 32MB by default. Already bumped to 128MB each, nothing changed.

Comment: @DavidMagalhães: there are quite a few different settings you can tune. The [Postgres Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) is a good place to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you likely have not updated the statistics on the Postgres database. With improper statistics, the database will not perform very well.

Comment: I activate autoVacuum, but nothing happen :(

Comment: you need to issue a VACUUM ANALYZE statement. Autovacuum will not help on a huge batch insert like this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Query

```sql
(
SELECT 1 AS n, left(plate, 2) AS l, plate, vin
FROM   imtt_vin
WHERE  left(plate, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
AND    manufacturer ILIKE '%".self::$Manufacturer."%'
AND    vin LIKE ?   -- You probably mean: vin = ?
ORDER  BY l, plate
)

UNION ALL
(
SELECT 3 AS n, substr(plate, 4, 2) AS l, plate, vin
FROM   imtt_vin
WHERE  substr(plate, 4, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
AND    manufacturer ILIKE '%".self::$Manufacturer."%'
AND    vin LIKE ?
ORDER  BY l, plate
)

UNION  ALL ...
```

- Use [**`UNION ALL`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION). `UNION` would be used to fold duplicates, which is obviously not the case here, and would be more expensive.
- Since your leading ORDER BY item is `n`, it's probably more efficient to order individual legs of the query. The extra set of parentheses is needed for that.
- `left (plate, 2)` is a bit faster than `substr(plate, 1, 2)`. Works only for leading substrings (your first `SELECT`).

#### Index

A default [B-tree index only works for left-anchored `LIKE` expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684). But a **trigram GiST or GIN index** can be used for non-left-anchored patterns. You need the additional module [**`pg_trgm`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). Install once per database with [`CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) in PostgreSQL 9.1 or later. Consult the manual for older versions.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

I don't have much information to go on, basic [**partial GIN indexes**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) should work *wonders*:

```sql
CREATE INDEX imtt_vin_partial_gist_idx ON imtt_vin
USING  gin (manufacturer gin_trgm_ops)
WHERE  left(plate, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z';

CREATE INDEX imtt_vin_partial_gist_idx ON imtt_vin
USING  gin (manufacturer gin_trgm_ops)
WHERE  substr(plate, 4, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z';

-- more ...
```

- I didn't include `vin` in the index, since you probably want the equality operator `=` there.
- Predicates on a partial index have to be repeated (more or less) in queries so the query planner understands the index is applicable.
- A trigram index works for case insensitive matches.
- Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` whether the index is actually used. If it is, query time should be a matter of **milliseconds**, not seconds.
- The speed comes at a (small) cost for write operations for index maintenance. And The index is typically several times the size of the table on disk.
- You can't do any of this with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't provided enough information -- what indexes do you have, EXPLAIN ANALYZE output for slow queries, etc.

Some thoughts on optimizing your example query:

1: UTF-8 string functions are generally not very fast. If you want to speed up string functions, use the `bytea` type instead of varchar for this column (or change your whole database encoding to `SQL_ASCII`, but this is unadvisable)

2: Given your queries, the database probably has to go through *all* rows in the table and compute these string functions for each.

I don't know how many matches they have, so the index might not be useful, but functional indexes might help you out:

```
 CREATE INDEX imtt_vin_plate_1 ON imtt_vin (substr(plate,1,1));
 CREATE INDEX imtt_vin_plate_4 ON imtt_vin (substr(plate,4,1));
 CREATE INDEX imtt_vin_plate_7 ON imtt_vin (substr(plate,7,1));
```

3: If you can tolerate duplicate outputs, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` in your queries -- this will save you some processing with larger result sets.

4: Avoid `LIKE`/`ILIKE` whenever you can.